# Rank 3 permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G \leq Sym(\Omega)$ be a finite permutation group of rank 3, $\alpha \in \Omega$ and $g,h \in G$ such that $x_1 := g(\alpha)$ and $x_2 := h(\alpha)$ are not equal. Now my question is: Is there some $\beta \in \Omega$ such that $\alpha$, $x_1$ are in the same orbit under the action of $G_\beta$, but $x_2$ is contained in a different orbit of $G_\beta$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to assume that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are different from $\alpha$. Otherwise you could get a counterexample by taking $x_2 = \alpha$. Also $g$ and $h$ do not seem to have much relevance to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are counterexamples in which $G$ is imprimitive with blocks of size $2$, such as $C_2 \wr S_n$. Take $\alpha$ and $x_2$ to be in the same block and $x_1$ in a different block. Then there is no such $\beta$.

Perhaps you should assume that $G$ is primitive. In that case the answer might be yes, but I am not sure.

Comment: I am still wondering why the statement under the assumption of primitivity could be true. Do you have any clue? What could be a good starting point for a proof?

Comment: Sorry but I have do not have any immediate ideas on how to go about proving this. I tried lots of examples, and I was finding that the larger the group got the easier it became to find $\beta$ because there was more choice, but I could not see any way of approaching it systematically.

Comment: Hm, what about considering the matrix $A$ defined by $A_{ij}=\lvert G_i \cap g_j G_\alpha \rvert$, where $(g_j G_\alpha)_j$, $j\in \Omega$, are the cosets of $G_\alpha$ in $G$? If $A$ has full rank, each pair of columns is different which might answer the question. Therefore, assuming the primitivity of $G$, one has to prove that $A$ has full rank. At least if $G$ is imprimitive then the blocks can be seen somehow in the form of $A$.